# How do I pass constructor arguments to a Flask Blueprint?

Tags: python, flask

In a Flask website, I want to create a Blueprint called **gallery** which is a lightbox/art gallery application, but have multiple instances of it. For example,

```
app.register_blueprint(gallery,url_prefix='/photos')
app.register_blueprint(gallery,url_prefix='/paintings')
```

However I want the two instances of gallery to have entirely independent content sources, so the Blueprint needs an additional argument, i.e.

```
app.register_blueprint(gallery,url_prefix='/photos',source_directory='content/photos/')
app.register_blueprint(gallery,url_prefix='/paintings',source_directory='content/paintings/')
```

How do I make this possible? Alternatively can I access what **url_prefix** was in the Blueprint itself?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if Flask implements all of the routing stuff that Werkzeug does (Flask is based on Werkzeug), but in werkzeug you can use an `any` route, like so:

```
gallery = Blueprint(__name__, __name__, url_prefix='/<any("photos,paintings"):source>')
```

If you use `@gallery.route` on your views, you'll get an argument `source`, which you can use to determine your source directory.

```
@gallery.route('/show')
def show(source):
    # Show stuff based on source being "photos" or "paintings"
```

Not sure if that works in Flask, but worth a shot...

Answer (score 0):

There are several attributes of `request` object can be used to get `url_prefix` of a Blueprint object.

Perhaps `request.script_root` is simply what you want. For more information, the [Flask documentation about request object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.url) is recommended.