# How to pass arbitrary arguments to a flask blueprint?

Tags: python, oop, flask, arguments, blueprint

I have a flask api which I have wrapped up in an object. Doing this has made unit testing a breeze, because I can instantiate the api with a variety of different settings depending on whether it is in production, test, or whatehaveyou.

I am now trying to extend the api a bit, and for that I'm using a blueprint. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to pass arguments to the blueprint. My routes require information like which database to access, and that information is not static. How can I pass this information into a blueprint? I have included code below as an example:

api.py:

```
class MyApi(object):
    def __init__(self, databaseURI):
     self.app = Flask(__name__)
     self.app.register_blueprint(myblueprint)
```

blueprint.py

```
myblueprint= Blueprint('myblueprint', __name__)
@myblueprint.route('/route', methods=['GET'])
def route():
  database = OpenDatabaseConnection(databaseURI)
```

There is a related question here:
[How do I pass constructor arguments to a Flask Blueprint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969973/how-do-i-pass-constructor-arguments-to-a-flask-blueprint)

But the people who answer the question solve the op's use-case specific problem *without* actually answering the question of how to pass arbitrary arguments to a blueprint.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could create the blueprint dynamically in a constructor function:

```
def construct_blueprint(database):

    myblueprint = Blueprint('myblueprint', __name__)

    @myblueprint.route('/route', methods=['GET'])
    def route():
        database = database

    return(myblueprint)
```

Comment: Great idea! And I certainly appreciate it. The problem here is that part of the reason I wanted to use a blueprint was for the sake of organization. I don't really want a multi-thousand line long python file. I want to split the blueprints into respective files. To my knowledge, it isn't possible to spread a class definition across multiple files in python. I realize I could create a chain of "extension" classes, but that seems a bit hackish.

Comment: What is stopping you from putting that function in a module and then using it `myblueprint = module.construct_blueprint(database)`?

Comment: Only my end-of-the-day tiredness. Thank you sir.

Comment: Very elegant solution. Especially when using the integration of SQLAlchemy, BCrypt etc., this offers a very easy way to pass existing components down the chain. In addition one might basically also build a route-factory if such a need arises. In case people need to use the Flask app in this constructor function, use `current_app` (works only inside a route-decorated function of course), e.g. `current_app.loggerl.info(...)` if you have configured the Flask logger and so on.

Answer (score 6):

Use [Flask config system](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/config/) (`app.config`) to store all your config data, then from your Blueprint read your [Application Context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/appcontext/) using `current_app`.

Store in `app.config`:

```
app.config[DATABASE_URI] = databaseURI
```

Read application context:

```
databaseURI = current_app.config[DATABASE_URI]
```

**Sample code**

main.py

```
from flask import Flask
from blueprint import myblueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(myblueprint)
app.config[DATABASE_URI] = databaseURI
```

blueprint.py

```
from flask import current_app

myblueprint= Blueprint('myblueprint', __name__)
@myblueprint.route('/route', methods=['GET'])
def route():
  databaseURI = current_app.config[DATABASE_URI]
  database = OpenDatabaseConnection(databaseURI)
```

Answer (score 0):

This way it's possible to add a blueprint, passing parameters, inside an appfactory. Sometimes you'll need it and it's not described anywhere in the flask docs.

Assuming bp1.py, bp2.py are in the same folder as your `appname`

```
from appname import bp1, bp2

app.register_blueprint(bp1.bp)
# with parameters:
app.register_blueprint(bp2.construct_blueprint(arg1, arg2))
```

inside `bp2.py`:

```
def construct_blueprint(arg1, arg2):
    bp = Blueprint("bp2", __name__)

    @bp.route('/test')
    def test():
        ret = {'arg1': arg1, 'arg2': arg2}
        return jsonify(ret)

    return bp
```

Answer (score 0):

I went about this in a slightly different way by creating a class in the helper blueprints python files. This way I can have one call to load the class and then pass the result to the blueprint function in the main python script. When I load the class I can pass any attributes I've configured. I like this approach as it keeps my code much cleaner.

The code I've put in here can also be found at https://github.com/dacoburn/example-flask-blueprints if you want to download it. I added comments to the github with more details of what is going on in the python files.

The folder structure I have is:
src
|___main.py
|___routes
|___index.py
|___example.py
|___templates
|___index.html
|___example.html

`main.py`

```
from flask import Flask
import os
from routes.index import Index
from routes.example import Example

app = Flask(__name__)
index = Index("Example User")
example = Example("Random Arg")
app.register_blueprint(index.index)
app.register_blueprint(example.example)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('APP_PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

`index.py`

```
from flask import render_template, Blueprint


class Index:

    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username
        self.index = self.create_index()

    def create_index(self):
        index_page = Blueprint("index", __name__)

        @index_page.route("/", methods=['GET'])
        def index():
            return render_template("index.html", username=self.username)

        return index_page
```

`example.py`

```
from flask import render_template, Blueprint


class Example:

    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
        self.example = self.create_example()

    def create_example(self):
        example_page = Blueprint("example", __name__)

        @example_page.route("/<username>", methods=['GET'])
        def example(username):
            return render_template("example.html",
                                   username=username,
                                   arg=self.arg)

        return example_page
```

`index.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Hello {{ username }}</p>
    <br>
    This page also has a redirect to another route:
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/{{ username }}">Example Page</a></li>
    </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

`example.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example Page 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Hello {{ username }}</p>
    <br>
    Here is the random argument: {{ arg }}
    <br>
    <br>
    This page also has a link to the main page:
    <ul>
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('index.index') }}">Index Page</a></li>
    </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```