# Flask pass a variable from apps main file to a blueprint

Tags: python, flask

**How can i pass a variable to a blueprint from the apps main file**

Lets say i had the following sample app.

```
#app.py

from flask import Flask
from example_blueprint import example_blueprint

data_to_pass="Hurray, You passed me"
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(example_blueprint)
```

```
#Blueprint

from flask import Blueprint

example_blueprint = Blueprint('example_blueprint', __name__)

@example_blueprint.route('/')
def index():
    return "This is an example app"
```

How do i pass `data_to_pass` to the blueprint ?? 
Is there a flask inbuilt way?
I am trying to avoid importing the whole `app.py` file...it doesnt seem elegant.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a configuration variable, then you could in your `app.py` add like this `app.config['data_to_pass']` and in your `blueprint.py` you could `from flask import current_app` and then you can use it like this `current_app.config['data_to_pass']`. So the code should look like this:

```py
#app.py

from flask import Flask
from example_blueprint import example_blueprint

data_to_pass="Hurray, You passed me"
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['data_to_pass'] = data_to_pass

app.register_blueprint(example_blueprint)
```

and then in the blueprint, you can read it like this

```py
#Blueprint

from flask import Blueprint, current_app

example_blueprint = Blueprint('example_blueprint', __name__)

@example_blueprint.route('/')
def index():
    data_to_pass = current_app.config['data_to_pass']
    return "This is an example app"
```

This is the best way to use configuration variables I think.

Comment: i hadn't looked it that way..that's smart...would it possibly work with functions...or  import statements?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't tried that, because, with e.g. functions, I do import them from the app, like `from app import my_function` and similar with statements. The `current_app.config` is meant for passing variables as described in the official [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/)

Comment: Yeah i just read the documentation...its for passing configuration meaning custom variables wouldn't work. Also functions obviously

Comment: Yes, for the configuration meaning variables, but you can use that also. Or you could even use `flask.session` as it would be available globally also. But passing functions... I would offer simply to import where and when you need it.

Comment: I''ll check out flask session but i think i found a better way calling the blueprint programatically and encapsulating into a class.
I marked my question duplicate after i saw the answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640081/how-to-pass-arbitrary-arguments-to-a-flask-blueprint

However your method is very handy...i could pass one password and username to all my blueprint api's